Combine User Profiles
Windows 11 Professional----
I have two users as a result of the computer shop bringing files from previous computer to this new Dell XPS 8960. One is Jerry and the other is Jerry.GerryComputer. I specifically asked the shop to ensure that I ended up with just Gerry, but that didn't work out. I suspect this is a factor in my inability to bring up an app (Microsoft Flight Simulator X).  It worked fine on my Dell 8500 with Windows 10.  Can I combine the two users?  Does one take precedence? Of course, there are also the usual Administrator, Default, and Public users.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no formal way to transfer a user from one machine to another machine.  User profiles are machine specific even if they share the same username. I would just copy the required data from the old profile to the new profile.  If necessary i would take ownership of the data from the original profile.

" inability to bring up an app (Microsoft Flight Simulator X)" The app is installed for one user and not the other. Likely, it must be installed per user. Try downloading and reinstalling, https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=8986
